# ST ROM Bootloader boot0 pin

Tags: pins, bootloader, rom, st

How is the boot0 pin is intended to be used by ST chip designers in real world applications? Once the boot0 pin is set high, the chip executes the bootloader section in memory and it will not go back to the execution of application section of memory unless the boot0 pin is set low. How can the user switch that pin back to low to recover the application firmware execution, after flashing a new application firmware, while the STM32 is in bootloader mode? It is an STM32H723ZG.

Our intention is to have a firmware upgrade over the air via CANBus. We were not sure how are we going to achieve that using the ST embedded ROM bootloader.

While a "healthy" application is running in the STM32, we can potentially configure a circuit to set the boot0 pin and trigger a reset on NRST pin, using a GPIO pin to control that circuit (please suggest any circuit ideas). Then the bootloader will take over and flash the firmware.

Now how do we get back to the application memory section? Since our circuit will be latched with the boot0 pin high and there is no firmware running to reset it remotely back to low.

Please see my complete test process on another thread about the CANBus issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75686133/st-rom-bootloader-fdcan-canbus

Comment: I would guess, perhaps by letting go of the button that makes it high?

Comment: If you have a circuit that can latch the state, the circuit must also start it in unlatched state. How about making it require a power cycle to go low? However, you can just exit the bootloader by saying go execute code from flash if that helps to set the pin low on boot. You can likely jump to execute bootloader from your application, and you can also jump to execute code in RAM, so regardless of hardware, you can do pretty much whatever you want. Normally you'd just have a update pushbutton or switch. Activating that on powerup or reset (maybe with reset button) makes it run bootloader.